# generate solution file on command line (create new solution from scratch)?

Tags: c#, command-line, mono, projects-and-solutions, sharpdevelop

Is there a command line tool (I'm in cygwin specifically) which can generate template solution files for me? When I use the Sharpdevlop GUI and say I'm doing a new project, I am prompted with choices that I can choose from, and then SharpDevelop automagically makes .sln, .csproj, .cs, etc files for me. If all that's happening is that templates are being copied over and a few variable fields filled in (like project name), then it's just as possible to do this on the cli.

In my mind it would look like this:

```
$ #remember: I'm in Cygwin if that matters

$ ls
./ ../

$ sharpdevelop-init "Windows Application" Test  #or mono-init or something...

$ ls -R
.:
Test/  Test.sln

./Test:
MainForm.Designer.cs  Program.cs   Test.csproj  obj/
MainForm.cs           Properties/  bin/

..... etc ....
```

Is there such a command line tool? Mono obviously does exactly what I want, but I want to know the command line interface to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such command line application that does this as far as I am aware.

The closest thing to such an application in my opinion is using [PowerShell and NuGet](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2011/06/12/InstallingNuGetPackagesOutsideVisualStudio.aspx) to automate SharpDevelop from the command line allowing you to install NuGet packages. A NuGet package could contain your file templates. This does not match what you are trying to do since the solution and project files need to have already been created.