# Creating a .Net solution on the command line with mono

Tags: .net, command-line, mono, command-line-interface, csproj

I run Linux and have Mono installed, I do not have MonoDevelop installed. I would like to create solution and csproj files from the command line. How do I do this? [A similar question has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454212/generate-solution-file-on-command-line-create-new-solution-from-scratch), it was asked some time ago, with an answer stating it can't be done. But I can't accept this is the case. It appears Microsoft has a such a tool, [projectgen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc175307(v=vs.90).aspx), at least for projects.

If this truly is not possible what other options do I have? Do I need to hand generate templates and then modify them when I create new solutions and projects? Or do I need to install MonoDevelop and open it up just to create solution and project files? Any other ideas to manage the this process?

Comment: possible duplicate of [generate solution file on command line (create new solution from scratch)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454212/generate-solution-file-on-command-line-create-new-solution-from-scratch)

Comment: I don't see any change made in this area, unless you plan to write your own command line utility to serve yourself. Thus, I voted to close this question as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it for now. But if you really want to fix this situation, I recommend that you contribute a new option to the "mdtool" command line tool that is part of MonoDevelop.