# Running NUnit Tests On Ubuntu: An exception occurred in the driver while loading tests

Tags: ubuntu, mono, nunit

I have installed mono-complete, nuget and nunit.

I am using NUnit Console Runner to run nunit test cases.

NUnit Console Runner 3.7.0
Copyright (c) 2017 Charlie Poole, Rob Prouse

Runtime Environment
   OS Version: Linux 4.4.0.1020
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.17020

Test Files
    SampleNUnit.dll

Errors, Failures and Warnings

1) Error :
An exception occurred in the driver while loading tests.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object:__icall_wrapper_mono_remoting_wrapper (intptr,intptr)
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke) NUnit.Engine.Agents.RemoteTestAgent:Run (NUnit.Engine.ITestEventListener,NUnit.Engine.TestFilter)
  at NUnit.Engine.Runners.ProcessRunner.RunTests (ITestEventListener listener, NUnit.Engine.TestFilter filter) <0x40ae1bb0 + 0x000ae> in :0

Test Run Summary
  Overall result: Failed
  Test Count: 0, Passed: 0, Failed: 0, Warnings: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 0
  Start time: 2017-07-24 22:38:51Z
    End time: 2017-07-24 22:38:51Z
    Duration: 0.403 seconds

Thanks for the help so that I can run NUnit test cases.

Answer (score 0):

In the related [NUnit issue](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/270) you mention that you compile the one test file using `mcs`. If instead you compile using `xbuild` on your version of Mono (`msbuild` on newer versions), you will find that it works as expected.

```
xbuild /p:Configuration=Release NUnitTest.sln
```

Comment: I can get it to work with xbuild. That is:
xbuild /p:TargetFrameworkVersion="v4.5" /p:Configuration=Release SampleNUNIT.sln

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245811/creating-a-net-solution-on-the-command-line-with-mono that xbuild is no replacement for a command line approach.

Comment: It is true that xbuild isn't a good solution for creating project files, but straight `mcs` won't add references or deal with multiple `cs` files without complicated command line options. Working that way would not be maintainable for a project of any size. .NET has a project system, to not use it is asking for trouble. I agree that Mono doesn't have a good solution for this from the command line, but that doesn't change the fact that you should be using project files. I would actually recommend switching to .NET Core which does have a good command line option, `dotnet new`.